# Running powershell script inside TeamCity exits with error, but no error in console

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, teamcity

One of my powershell build steps is having an issue that only seems to happen when run from within TeamCity. I can run the same file from a powershell console without an error.

```
$loadedAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\\powershell\\AWSSDK.dll")
$accessKeyID="1234"
$secretKeyID="1234"
$client=[Amazon.AWSClientFactory]::CreateAmazonEC2Client($accessKeyID,$secretKeyID)
```

The error in TeamCity is

```
[04:38:22][Step 2/2] T:\TeamCity\BuildAgent2\temp\buildTmp\powershell2271598119506819752.ps1 : 
[04:38:22][Step 2/2] Exception calling "CreateAmazonEC2Client" with "2" argument(s): "No 
[04:38:22][Step 2/2] RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured"
[04:38:22][Step 2/2]     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], MethodInvocatio 
[04:38:22][Step 2/2]    nException
[04:38:22][Step 2/2]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationExc 
[04:38:22][Step 2/2]    eption,powershell2271598119506819752.ps1
[04:38:22][Step 2/2]  
[04:38:22][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 1
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the powershell console from inside an EC2 instance, it is very likely that you've been prompted to set a default region. If your default region got set in the SDK store, that configuration is [shared between AWS Powershell and the AWS .NET SDK](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx1310VG2O81PSY/Referencing-Credentials-using-Profiles).

This configuration *is not shared across Windows users*, so it is very possible that your TeamCity agent is running on some other user (system user?) that isn't aware of the configuration changes you've made in the console.

A couple of easy options:

1. Use a different [CreateAmazonEC2Client constructor](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_AWSClientFactory_CreateAmazonEC2Client_8.htm) to explicitly specify your region. The region seems to be the only piece of data missing for this initial step.

Example:

```
public static AmazonEC2 CreateAmazonEC2Client(
    string awsAccessKey,
    string awsSecretAccessKey,
    RegionEndpoint region
)
```

2. Use the [AWS Powershell Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) instead. You may find it easier to programatically manage your credentials and configurations, and especially for something like TeamCity (where powershell may not be invoked by the same windows user that you are using to RDP into an EC2 instance, or more importantly, the same user that you are managing configurations on in *your* powershell sessions) it is useful because you can explicitly set your session defaults via `Initialize-AWSDefaults`.